# Recoding single variable based on multiple variables

Tags: r

I have a dataset with more than 150,000 rows and about 40 variables. In my dataset, each row represents an encounter with an individual, and each has a unique ID. However, some individuals come back several times over a period of time, and I would like to be able to reflect this so that the unique ID becomes specific to the individual rather than the encounter.

Here's a sample dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(
  ID = c(101:110),
  Name = c("AA", "BB", "AA", "DD", "EE", "FF", "AA", "GG", "DD", "HH"),
  Age = c(1, 56, 1, 72, 12, 43, 1, 32, 72, 99),
  Group = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 3, 2, 4),
  Date = seq(from = as.Date("2019-01-01"), to = as.Date("2019-01-10"), by = 'day'), 
  Order = c("re-do", "first", "first", "first", "re-do", "first", "re-do", "first", "re-do", "first"),
  Site = c(2, 54, 2, 522, 3, 490, 2, 23, 522, 21)
)
```

Which looks like this:

```
    ID Name Age Group       Date Order Site
1  101   AA   1     1 2019-01-01 re-do    2
2  102   BB  56     2 2019-01-02 first   54
3  103   AA   1     1 2019-01-03 first    2
4  104   DD  72     2 2019-01-04 first  522
5  105   EE  12     1 2019-01-05 re-do    3
6  106   FF  43     4 2019-01-06 first  490
7  107   AA   1     1 2019-01-07 re-do    2
8  108   GG  32     3 2019-01-08 first   23
9  109   DD  72     2 2019-01-09 re-do  522
10 110   HH  99     4 2019-01-10 first   21
```

In order for the column value (in the "ID" column) to be made the same, the following conditions has to be met:

- The row ID value to be copied has to be from a row with the Order
  "first"
- The row(s) to have new ID value has to be from a row with the order
  "re-do"
- They have to identical values in the columns `"name" + "age" + "group" + "site"`
- The date of the rows to have new ID value has to be a date occurring
  after the "first"

The final dataset should look like this:

```
      ID Name    Age Group Date       Order  Site
   <dbl> <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <date>     <fct> <dbl>
 1   101 AA        1     1 2019-01-01 re-do     2
 2   102 BB       56     2 2019-01-02 first    54
 3   103 AA        1     1 2019-01-03 first     2
 4   104 DD       72     2 2019-01-04 first   522
 5   105 EE       12     1 2019-01-05 re-do     3
 6   106 FF       43     4 2019-01-06 first   490
 7   103 AA        1     1 2019-01-07 re-do     2
 8   108 GG       32     3 2019-01-08 first    23
 9   104 DD       72     2 2019-01-09 re-do   522
10   110 HH       99     4 2019-01-10 first    21
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is a great first post! I removed the 'thank you' and introduction not strictly related to the problem. I hope you're ok with that.

Comment: Sorry. I meant for the original question. I think the further conditions in the `Order` column will be hard to use in `hutils::duplicated_rows`.

Answer (score 1):

What would you like to do in case more than one patient happens to have the same values for `Name, Age, Group, Site`?

What you suggested would be doable by something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(Name, Age, Group, Site) %>% 
  mutate(first_date = ifelse(Order == "first", 
                             Date, 
                             Date[Order == "first"])) %>%
  mutate(ID = ifelse(n() > 1 & Date >= first_date, 
                     ID[Order == "first"], 
                     ID)) %>%
  select(-first_date)
```

But if you have more than one patient re-doing the task, you might attribute subsequent "re-do" entries to the wrong patient. You might want to check whether that case occurs at all:

```
df %>% 
  filter(Order == "first") %>% 
  group_by(Name, Age, Group, Site) %>% 
  filter(n() > 1)
```

If yes, you could e.g. decide on a time window within which you attribute subsequent entries to either of the patients, or attribute all "re-do" entries until the second "first" to the first patient and all others to the next, or just exclude all multi-person entries, depending on how important accuracy and completeness are here, respectively.

Comment: that does the trick - regarding time frames (and a separate query about missing values) I'll have a bit more of an explore of my dataset and then ask as a new question. Thanks!

Comment: the code works perfect in the little sample dataframe above, but on my massive (~150,000 rows) dataset I've noticed some peculiarities and have been trying to identify the problem - I find it drops loads of `ID`, including some from `Order == "first"` group, and unpicking the mutate code I cannot find any pattern to it. Furthermore, I have more `ID` than `Order == "first"`, which shouldn't be the case with the above code. Any thoughts?

Comment: Hard to say without looking at the data that produces these errors. 

Does `first_date` get assigned correctly? You can check this by running everything except for `select(-first_date)`. 

Perhaps you have "first" response data from multiple people with the same set of identifiers on the same day. Does it still happen if you add `& Order != "first"` to the conditions in the second `mutate()`?

Comment: Also, I'd check for which IDs exactly are dropped, `setdiff(unique(df$ID), unique(df_after_transformation$ID))`, and check what's wrong with these entries in particular.

Comment: Having removed the `select(-first_date)` I can see the value in this column for about 30,000 rows is `NA`. Going through this, they are all `"re-do"` and some of these would have qualified for copying of `ID` but it hasn't happened as the date was missing. Ensuring the `first_date` column is as a date (using `as.Date.numeric()`) didn't alter the outcome for the remaining. Adding in the `& Order != "first"` didn't improve the output either (oddly enough made the numbers paired less).

Comment: Furthermore, looking at the ones that have their `ID` copied some are both `"first"`, which doesn't meet the conditional (and they're on different dates). And all `ID` that have been dropped also have their `first_date` dropped (but not all `first_date` that have been dropped have the `ID` dropped).